# SQL Update for duplicate record

Tags: sql-server

I want to update AccountID of contact(ContactActID) table with original AccountID using DuplicateId ref to PrimaryId

Below is my select query:

```
SELECT  AD.primaryid, 
        AD.actID, 
        AD.accountname, 
        AD.duplicateID, 
        C.Actid AS [ContactActID],
        C.ContactId,
        C.Contactname 
FROM  Contact09072018 C
INNER JOIN AccountDump AD ON C.actid=AD.actid
ORDER BY AD.primaryid
```

result Of above Query:

```
primaryid  actID          accountname            duplicateID ContactActID  ContactId Contactname 
1          2499   A SERVICE INDIA PRIVATE LIMITED   0               2499    2879    Rajesh 
1          2499   A SERVICE INDIA PRIVATE LIMITED   0               2499    3063    Deepak 
1          2499   A SERVICE INDIA PRIVATE LIMITED   0               2499    3064    Rajesh Aiwale
2          22999  A SERVICE INDIA PVT LIMITED       1               22999   24245   Dinesh 
3          4484   A Service India Pvt Ltd           1               4484    5213    Siddharth 
3          4484   Ae Service India Pvt Ltd          1               4484    7008    Rajesh 
4          11524  An Pvt Ltd                        0               11524   12514   Abhijit 
5          22963  Ansa Pvt Ltd.                     4               22963   24204   Mr Abhijit
6          5059   Arm                               7               5059    5872    Mafasal 
7          22992  Arm industries                    0               22992   24204  Muffazzal
```

Required data with updated ContactActID:

```
primaryid actID          accountname            duplicateID ContactActID  ContactId Contactname 
1   2499    A SERVICE INDIA PRIVATE LIMITED     0           2499            2879    Rajesh 
1   2499    A SERVICE INDIA PRIVATE LIMITED     0           2499            3063    Deepak 
1   2499    A SERVICE INDIA PRIVATE LIMITED     0           2499            3064    Rajesh 
2   22999   A SERVICE INDIA PVT LIMITED         1           2499            24245   Dinesh 
3   4484    A Service India Pvt Ltd             1           2499            5213    Siddharth 
3   4484    Ae Service India Pvt Ltd            1           2499            7008    Rajesh 
4   11524   An Pvt Ltd                          0           11524           12514   Abhijit 
5   22963   Ansa Pvt Ltd.                       4           11524           24204   Mr Abhijit
6   5059    Arm                                 7           22992           5872    Mafasal 
7   22992   Arm industries                      0           22992           24238 Muffazzal
```

Comment: Post the query you have tried to achieve this.

Comment: well to update data you have to write an `UPDATE` query to begin with...secondly you need to only return those rows which have the DuplicateID flag set  to be > 0. Thirdly you then need to join back to the same table based on the duplicate ID in order to obtain the correct contact ID

Comment: FYI your query column names do not match your output where you write `result Of above Query:`

Comment: How does the `ContactId` of the last row magically change???  What's your logic???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to pick up

> [ContactActID]

needs to be changed

```
       SELECT  AD.primaryid, 
        AD.actID, 
        AD.accountname, 
        AD.duplicateID, 
        CASE 
        WHEN AD.duplicateID=0
        THEN C.Actid
        ELSE (SELECT DISTINCT t2.actID FROM AccountDump t2 WHERE t2.primaryid=AD.duplicateID) 
        END
        AS [ContactActID],
        C.ContactId,
        C.Contactname FROM  Contact09072018 C
INNER JOIN AccountDump AD ON C.actid=AD.actid
ORDER BY AD.primaryid
```